# Write a script tag just before </body> in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Web Site with custom made themes. These themes are invoked using a BasePage that every page inherits, where the masterpagefile is set dynamically.

I want to add a tracking script to every page, but I don't want to include a <%= TrackingScript %> on every theme masterpage.

I want to do it programmatically from the BasePage.

RegisterStartupScript won't work, because not every page contains a form runat="server"...

I'm running out of ideas, so I tought someine in here had an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution here, but it's not one that I would recommend very strongly.  It's got the same built in brittleness as developers forgetting to put in a block of script tags, or making them remember to put "body runat=server", or other such techniques, but it's slightly less likely that they'll forget a "" tag.

Basically, you can iterate the literal tags in the page during PreRender, find the closing body tag, and insert your script before it.  But again, if your master page developers forget a /body tag, it won't work.  You could beef it up to also look for /html or at the very worst, just simply do a `Page.Controls.Add()` to make it appear after everything, but that's not valid html.

Here's the code (adapted from a quick example I found [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/640436/657167.aspx)):

```
public void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = -1;
            var control = FindBodyTag(this, out x);
            this.Page.Controls.AddAt(x, new LiteralControl("test"));
        }


        public LiteralControl FindBodyTag(Control parentCtl, out int ctlPos)
        {
            LiteralControl bodyTag = null;
            ctlPos = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < parentCtl.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                var currentCtl = parentCtl.Controls[i];
                if (currentCtl is LiteralControl)
                {
                    int iPos = (currentCtl as LiteralControl).Text.ToLower().IndexOf("</body");
                    if (iPos > -1)
                   {
                       ctlPos = i;
                        break;
                   }
                }
            }
            return bodyTag;
        }
```

I would prefer a solution with a base masterpage class that exposed a BodyTag property that your Page could access and manipulate.

Comment: The best thing would be for the BaseMasterPage to add the script automatically.

Comment: Agreed.  Although I thought you said you wanted to do it from your base page class.  If a base master page will work for you, even better, it can find its own body tag.

Comment: Ok. I'm just wondering how that affects performance. To loop through the controls collection on every page view...?

Comment: As long as you don't have thousands of controls, and you're not recursively searching every control on the page (you don't need to if you're just looking for literals at the top level of the page's control heirarchy), then I doubt it's even noticeable.  You could even cache the index that you need to add it at if you're worried about it.

Comment: The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.

Guess I have to do it on PreInit, maybe?

Comment: PreInit doesn't work... Can you even modify the controls collection of the page?

Comment: Yes, you can.  The code I posted works fine on my machine.  You might want to google that error you are experiencing, it's a very frustrating one. It could be related to databinding or some other control on your page.

Comment: DataBinding happens several places. Can't ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

The Response.Filter property might be useful if you have inline code or other hindrances to modifying the Controls collection:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210510022033/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx

Otherwise Page.Master.FindControl("placeHolder"), or use a BaseMasterPage that adds the control programmatically.